# How run custom code before validate

Tags: jquery, django, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

I started with [Jquery.validate](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) to work. I try some tutorials but now I have come to a blocked state.

One this way I bind the rules and the messages to my form. Otherwise I do nothing with jquery on my form

```
$("#myform").validate({...})
```

Custom Code what I want to run.

```
$("#myform").find("#id_select_to").find("option").prop("selected", true);
```

How I can run custom code before the validation starts.

`"#id_select_to"` is the second pane what should get selected before validate. Widget is from the Django Admin.

[image: Widget from Django]

Comment: can u show complete code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my answer on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/6472021/548558

How I can run custom code.

```
$("#myform").validate({
    select: {
      required: {
        depends:function(){
           $("#myform").find("#id_select_to").find("option").prop("selected", true);
           return true;
        }
     },
   },
})
```

Works very well.